# Ubuntu MYSQL cannot connect from python script

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I need to create a mysql DB for my project. I have a ubuntu server and have followed this guide to install required modules:

https://www.javahelps.com/2018/10/install-mysql-with-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu.html

After installing everything I can reach the phpmyadmin using the browser 192.168.3.146/phpmyadmin works without any issues:
[phpmyadmin home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KmXw.png)

But the problem is when I try to reach the database through the python code, it does not work. My program hangs after mysql.connector.connect and will never print the next print statement.

```
print("trying MYSQL")
myConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host=192.168.3.146, user='test_user', passwd='test_user123', db='test', autocommit=True)
print("Connection ID:", myConnection)
print(myConnection)
```

I have previously sucesfully connected to the mysql this way to the mysql server which was created on Raspbian and did not have any issues. It seems that UBUNTU is not as straightforward.

Please can someone suggest me what could be the problem if I can easily reach the database through the web browser but python program fails

**UPDATE**

Trying out to comment out bind address in the configuration file but still no luck. The configuration file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVlku.png)

I have allowed firewall through port 3306 with the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

There is some progress. Now my Python program does not hang on the mysql connection but instead gives me error:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.3.251' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

First of all, I am unsure where does this IP come from 192.168.3.251. The machine am using to connect to the database is configured with static IP and it is 192.168.4.200. I do not know why it says 192.168.3.251

Answer (score 0):

Is the python script running from another machine? If so, maybe the problem is that mysql is listening only in localhost interface. You can change this by editing the file mysqld.cnf located in the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ folder and comment (with an #) the line that says:

bind-address = 127.0.0.1.

Once you've done this, restart the service this way:

$ sudo systemctl restart mysql.service

And, verify that everything is ok with:

$ systemctl status mysql.service

Comment: Yes it is running from another machine but it is connected to the same network. As I mentioned, on the other machine I can reach mysql through the web browser by typing in the server IP address 192.168.3.146/phpmyadmin. If I can reach it through the browser I dont understand why it wouldnt let me connect through the python script? I will try your solution anyways

Comment: When you type http://192.168.3.146/phpmyadmin in your browser, in fact you are not accesing MySQL directly but through a web site build upon PHP (phpmyadmin), which is executed by your web server (Apache I guess) which listen on port 80. In this scenario, the phpmyadmin connects to MySQL on localhost, port 3306. That's why is working through a web browser.

Comment: Thank you very much or explaining. I have commented out the line that you have suggested but still no luck. There is another line in the mysqld.cnf file simmilar to bind-address. It is mysqlx-bind-address. Do I comment out this as well?

Comment: Also, is it possible that it could be firewall related? When I have installed apache2 module on my ubuntu server, I could not access the index.html from the web browser untill I have  allowed apache through the firewall with the command ```ufw allow "Apache Full"```

Comment: ERROR 1130 means that you're not allowed to connect to MySQL using those credentilas. Basically, MySQL uses a combination of host, user and password to allow connections. root user is not allowed to access remotely by default so you have to change this or create another user to do so. An example would be:
CREATE USER 'mysql_usr'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* TO 'mysql_usr'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
The '%' means that the user can connect from any host. More info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html

Comment: Thanks for the response again.  Yes my problem was that I have created my user with the following command: ```CREATE USER 'mysql_usr'@'localhost'``` instead of  ```CREATE USER 'mysql_usr'@'%'```. Notice the localhost vs % difference.